# Angular: What is a best practice for changing a single div's class when multiple divs have the same class?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm fairly new to angular.  What I'd like to to is replace the class of a div when a button is clicked.  Using "ng-class" changes the class of all the divs with that class on the page, where I'd like to just select one to replace.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gstipton/XxMSm/25/) demonstrates what I'm trying to do.  I'm attempting to use jQuery, but as you can see it's not working in this context.  My guess is there is a more "angular-ish" way to do it.  Any suggestions?

Here is the code in the jsfiddle:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div class="test1">
    Text1
</div>
<div class="test1">
    Text2
</div>
<button ng-click="click($event)">Click</button>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

   $scope.click = function (e) {
       var source = e.target || e.srcElement;
       var div = source.prev("div.test1:first");
       div.toggleClass('test1');
   };
}

.test1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: ud like to select one ... which one?

Comment: In this instance I'd like to select the first one above it.  However, if you click the button in the fiddle it will log this error to the console: "TypeError: Object #<HTMLButtonElement> has no method 'prev'."  I'm also not convinced that jQuery is the best way to do it.

Comment: well angular by itself uses a condensed version of jQuery, so if you want to use things like .prev() you likely will need to bring in the standard jQuery library as well.

Comment: Yeah... I have jQuery on the path.  As far as I can tell, it should be configured to use it.  That's why I'm not sure why it's throwing that error.

Comment: It is throwing the error because `source` is a DOM element.  You need to wrap it in jQuery in order to call a jQuery method like prev():  `$(source).prev(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are trying to approach it in the rather non-AngularJS way. With AngularJS you need to focus on the model manipulation, decoratively describe UI and let AngularJS figure out the rest.

One way of approaching the problem would be something along those lines:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.selected = true;

    $scope.click = function () {
      $scope.selected = false;  
    }; 
}
```

and in HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-class="{test1: selected}">
        Text1
    </div>
    <div class="test1">
        Text2
    </div>
    <button ng-click="click()">Click</button>
</div>
```

Working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/CqHDn/ but this is really only one way of doing things. The key question here is this: what is so special about the first div (functionally speaking) that you want to flip classes of it? You should probably represent functional concepts in your model.

As far as jQuery goes: I would really suggest dropping it altogether while learning AngularJS. I'm not the only one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/1418796

Comment: great answer, and great reference.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.  I agree about jQuery..it felt wrong but I was taking a stab.  The simple functionality I'm really trying to get at is to expand/collapse a particular div on the screen when its corresponding button is clicked.  Since the div's class is repeated on the page, I'd like to find a way to change the one that was clicked.  I've updated my jsFiddle to reflect this a bit more closely.

Comment: @Geoff, this sounds like what you want: http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/#/collapse

Comment: Thnx @MarkRajcok, wanted to write the same in a comment here :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I'd looked at that and agree that it's what I want to do.  However, I didn't want to depend on a library before I understood how it should work.  It sounds like the answer is change my thinking.  Rather than figure out how to manipulate elements on the page, figure out how to feed the data from the model objects into the UI elements in a way that supports the desired functionality.