# How do I change the class of each individual div in a series of divs when clicked on?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to change the class of an individual div when it is clicked on and what I have is not working. I'm having trouble understanding how ng-click and ng-class work together so that is why I'm having trouble figuring this out. What do I need to do or put inside my changeBackground function so that individual div will have a class applied?

```
<div ng-controller="BoardController">
    <div class="rows" ng-repeat="r in rows track by $index" ng-click="changeBackground($index)" ng-class="{ red: }">

    </div>
</div>

$scope.changeBackground = function(index) {

};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular: What is a best practice for changing a single div's class when multiple divs have the same class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227536/angular-what-is-a-best-practice-for-changing-a-single-divs-class-when-multiple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<div ng-controller="BoardController">
    <div class="rows" ng-repeat="r in rows track by $index"
            ng-click="r.clicked = !r.clicked" ng-class="{ 'red':r.clicked }">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Rather than use conditionals in the html, how could it be done using a background javascript function that is called on ng-click like I had in my example?

Comment: I found what I was looking for at the bottom of this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545744/how-to-make-a-condition-on-ng-click-in-angularjs